# how to make assure the load order of images on canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I have two images to draw on canvas.

I would like to make sure A is shown on B.

```
var Apic = new Image();
var Bpic = new Image();

Apic.src = "Apic.png";
Bpic.src = "Bpic.png";

// I want to add z-index to 

Apic.style  =  "z-index:1;";
Bpic.style  =  "z-index:2;";

Apic.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(Apic 0,0);
};

Bpic.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(Bpic,0,0);
};
```

However,it doesn't work ,any good solution??

---

I have soloved the problem like this with Ken Fyrstenberg help.

Bpic is drawn on Apic every time.

It might not the good way though, it can solve the  problem for now.

```
Apic.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(Apic 0,0);
    context.drawImage(Bpic,0,0);
};

Bpic.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(Bpic,0,0);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put urls into an array. Create image elements in the same order to a parallel array. This will keep the order tight. Then you need to count the successful loads so we are sure we have all image data that is needed:

```
var urls = ["Apic.png", "Bpic.png"];      // url and order
var pics = [];                            // holds the image elements                 
var count = urls.length;                  // number of images to load

for(var i = 0, url; url = urls[i++];) {   // share onload handler
    var pic = new Image();                // create a new image
    pics.push(pic);                       // store in array
    pic.onload = loadCounter;             // set load handler (also add for error)
    pic.src = url;                        // set url to start loading
}

function loadCounter() {
    count--;
    if (!count) {                         // when done we can draw the images in order:
        for(var i = 0, pic; pic = pics[i++];) {
            context.drawImage(pic, 0, 0);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't use `count` as a function name then define `count` as a variable again. You're also missing a `,` in `context.drawImage(pic 0,0);`

Comment: I am glad to have your reply. However using array is a bit complex for my case. I simplified my sample though, I have a few pictures to load and place is not always (0,0) ,it changes depending on pictures.Is there a good way to use z-index?

Comment: @whitebear z-index does not affect drawings to canvas. You could just add the images inside a div on top of each other for that. For canvas you have to make sure all image data has loaded. If arrays are too complex, then just rewrite your original example to use shared loaders and draw when the two images has loaded. You can also check my [YAIL (LT)](https://github.com/epistemex/yail) image loader (free) which takes care of all the complex stuff.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg I see. z-index is not used for canvas. So I rewrite the images after the back image is loaded. It might load the image twice  though, it can slove the problem.